# Oracle create precedure with cursor loop

Tags: oracle, loops, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm creating a procedure in Oracle to search for some keywords specified in the parameter and print out the line. This is my code below. It works but I don't know why it keeps printing the last line twice. Please help

```
    CREATE TABLE Testimonial( TestimonialID integer PRIMARY KEY,
                Content char(100));

INSERT INTO Testimonial VALUES (100,'Great website');
INSERT INTO Testimonial VALUES (101,'I like it');
INSERT INTO Testimonial VALUES (102,'I bought two items from here and I really like them');
INSERT INTO Testimonial VALUES (103,'My girlfriends likes my presents I bought here');
INSERT INTO Testimonial VALUES (104,'Nice products');
INSERT INTO Testimonial VALUES (105,'Friendly customer service');

COMMIT;


Create or replace procedure Search_Testimonials (search_string IN char)
IS
        Testimonial_record   Testimonial%ROWTYPE;

 cursor cur_Testimonial is 
    select *
    from Testimonial
    WHERE content LIKE '%' || search_string || '%';
BEGIN
    open cur_Testimonial;
    Loop
        Fetch cur_Testimonial into Testimonial_record;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Content: ' || Testimonial_record.content );
        EXIT WHEN cur_Testimonial%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    close cur_Testimonial;
    COMMIT;
END;
/

set serveroutput on

exec Search_Testimonials('bought')
```

OUTPUT

```
Content: I bought two items from here and I really like them
Content: My girlfriends likes my presents I bought here
Content: My girlfriends likes my presents I bought here
```

Comment: I guess that it needs to move past the last record before NOTFOUND is true.

Comment: No, the simple reason is that NOTFOUND was being checked AFTER the call to DBMS_OUTPUT.

Answer (score 2):

This might work a bit better.

```
Loop
    Fetch cur_Testimonial into Testimonial_record;
    EXIT WHEN cur_Testimonial%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Content: ' || Testimonial_record.content );
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thanks a lot. Don't know why it makes different.

Comment: Because I guess it needs to move past the last record before it knows about NOTFOUND, and when it does, it must still contain the last record in .content